# UITableView doesn't reload content

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UITableView` embedded inside a `UIViewController` but am having a few problems. I've set the delegate of the table view to the view controller.

1) The data source is an array which is being retrieved from the internet. The problem is that when the data is downloaded and placed into the array and `[self.tipTableView reloadData]` has been called, it doesn't update the table. I can see that `numberOfRowsInSection:` is called and it returns the correct number (not 0) but it doesn't call `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. However, when the array has data in `viewDidLoad`, it loads it correctly.

2) I want to make the table hidden by default and then visible when a button is pressed. Setting the table to hidden in `viewDidLoad` works fine, but when I try to set it to visible when the button is pressed it doesn't work. I'm trying `self.tipTableView.hidden = NO;` for this, which only appears to work in `viewDidLoad` and not other methods.

The table view was created in interface builder, it's connected to the view controller as in this image:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why these problems are happening?

Thanks!

Comment: How and where do you create the table view?

Comment: The table view was created in interface builder, it's connected to the view controller as in this image [link](http://i.imgur.com/zsnWh.png). It works when the array's contents is available straight away in viewDidLoad but not when the data is being downloaded.

Comment: In your code you use `theTableView`, but in the image, the outlet is called `tipTableView`. Could this be the reason?

Comment: Apologies, I used theTableView in the question for example purposes. I just edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: When exactly do you call `[tableView reloadData]` ?

Comment: Did you verify, that the table view isn't `nil`, when you call `reloadData` or try to hide it?

Comment: In `connectionDidFinishLoading:` I parse the data to get the data into an array. Then at the end I call `[self.tipTableView reloadData];`. It calls `numberOfRowsInSection:` which returns the correct number in the array but no cells are actually created. I'm caching the data when it's downloaded from the web so the next time the view controller is loaded it has the array available in viewDidLoad, which is when it works.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the **cellForRowAtIndexPath** method is called for the cells which are currently visible on the screen. I guess while you are reloading your table it is still invisible. So maybe you should try to set hidden NO at first and then reload data immediately after that if there is data to show.

Answer (score 0):

**1:**

You have to implement at least the following methods in your datesource:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [yourarray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// that's up to you
}
```

I suppose you forgot to implement **numberoOfRowsInSection**.

**2:**

Try:

```
[self.tableView setHidden:NO];
```

That should work, provided you are not looping after showing it ( while (condition) do_something; ).

This is the case also if you are downloading something from the network in the main thread.

Comment: 1. All 3 of those methods are implemented in the datasource, as you ca see below:

`- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSLog(@"Number of Rows: %i", self.tips.count);
    
    return [self.tips count];
}`

Comment: 2. When I try this and then use NSLog on the tableView I can see that it sets hidden = YES as it should but the changes aren't actually made. The hidden attribute in the TableView is set correctly but the change isn't made on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you are not connecting your button that initiates the action properly, since you say that it works if you run it from your viewDidLoad method, but does not work when you connect the action to a button.

Are you connecting the button properly in IB?

Are you connecting it as an action or an outlet?

...Or are you just creating the button programmatically?